# Plotly express gant chart x axis date/time label

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have a timeline style chart using the plotly gantt function as [documented](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/).

My question is how to manually set the x-axis labels, in my example i have multiple years of data as image below so only want to plot months without the year
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To adjust x -axis use plotly time series [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/). In my example this was as below to retain month only

```py
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%b")
```